# Como chamar método Linq na View?

Tags: c#, linq

Bom dia pessoal.
a minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho o seguinte método no meu model:

```
public IQueryable GetConsulta()
{
    var q = (from c in Datacontext.Tabela1
                join b in Datacontext.Tabela2 on c.CodClase equals b.CodClase
                join d in Datacontext.Tabela3 on b.CodImobilizado equals d.CodImobilizado
                where c.CodClase == b.CodClase && b.CodImobilizado == d.CodImobilizado
                select new
                {
                    taxa = c.Taxa,
                    ano = DateTime.Parse(b.Data).Year,
                    data = d.Data,
                    valorAquisicao = b.Valor,

                });

    return q;
}
```

*Na View está assim:*

```
void getConsulta(){
    var a = model.GetConsulta();    
    foreach(var linha in a){
      //faça algo
    }
}
```

O problema é que não consigo acessar as variáveis criadas no método do model no foreach da View.

Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Comment: Você está retornando isso para a View?

Comment: sim Marconi. eu preciso acessar o resultado do select feito no model, dentro do ciclo foreach que aparece no método getconsulta que se encontra na viewer

Comment: E a resposta abaixo, acho que te ajuda. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no tipo de retorno que você está utilizando, nesta abordagem, você não especifica qual o retorno do IQueryable, consequentemente na view, você não vai conseguir visualizar os dados desejados.

Uma sugestão seria você tipar seu retorno com uma classe de modelo:

```
class Modelo {
    public string taxa { get; set; }
    public int ano { get; set; }
    public DateTime data { get; set; }
    public decimal valorAquisicao { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<Modelo> GetConsulta()
{
    var q = (from c in Datacontext.Tabela1
                join b in Datacontext.Tabela2 on c.CodClase equals b.CodClase
                join d in Datacontext.Tabela3 on b.CodImobilizado equals d.CodImobilizado
                where c.CodClase == b.CodClase && b.CodImobilizado == d.CodImobilizado
                select new Modelo()
                {
                    taxa = c.Taxa,
                    ano = DateTime.Parse(b.Data).Year,
                    data = d.Data,
                    valorAquisicao = b.Valor,

                });

    return q;
}
```

Na View ficaria assim:

```
void getConsulta(){
    var a = model.GetConsulta();    
    foreach(Modelo linha in a){
      //faça algo
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode ser isso mesmo, bem lembrado. :)

Comment: Provavelmente seja esta a situação.Neste caso a minha variavel q teria que ser do tipo modelo certo?

Comment: Sim, vou editar a resposta

Comment: Julio muitissimo obrigado. a sua resposta foi muito util Obrigado Mesmo. Nota: Sou novo neste forum. aonde posso marcar como resposta válida?

Comment: Abaixo do marcador de votos tem um V, basta clicar nele para marcar a resposta como válida.